# What is the impact of lack of stereoscopic vision on a first class medical in the EU?

Tags: easa-regulations, medical, pilot-certification

I have just completed aero-medical examination for first aviation class. I was refused due to the lack of stereoscopic vision. In the book with squares with circles in 3D, I saw only 4/9. The medical examiner said that I will get class 2 and if the aviation school issues a certificate that I can take off and land without any problems, he will "try" as an exception to approve class 1.

Does it make any sense to spend money and waste time, or am I already deleted? What are my chances?

PS. I'm from Poland.

Comment: In Canada you can hold a Cat 1 with vision in only one eye, so I would think it's worth a shot.

Comment: What are your goals with class 1 medical? Just recreational flying, or pro?